# What exactly did Aberforth Dumbledore do to the goats?

Tags: harry-potter

I remember in the last HP, there was something to the effect that Aberforth had been arrested for doing something with goats. Something like "using inappropriate charms on a goat."

What could he do to warrant arrest? It can't be what I think it is, can it?

Comment: This remind me of Troy McLure "doing something with fishes"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [Leaky Cauldron](http://the-leaky-cauldron.org/wiki/index.php?title=Aberforth_Dumbledore#Additional_Canon):

> J. K. Rowling was asked in 2007 what exactly Aberforth did to the goat to be prosecuted. Below is a transcript of the interview:
>   Q: *In the Goblet of Fire Dumbledore said his brother was prosecuted for practicing inappropriate charms [JKR buries her head, to laughter] on a goat; what were the inappropriate charms he was practicing on that goat?*
>   JKR: How old are you?
>   *Eight*.
>   JKR: I think that he was trying to make a goat that was easy to keep clean [laughter], curly horns. That's a joke that works on a couple of levels. I really like Aberforth and his goats. But you know Aberforth having this strange fondness for goats if you've read book seven, came in really useful to Harry, later on, because a goat, a stag, you know. If you're a stupid Death Eater, what's the difference. So, that is my answer to YOU.

Other than that...We don't know.

Comment: "So, that is my answer to YOU". Well I'd like to ask her the question myself, for I am definitely over 21 :P

Comment: @Kalissar One for Twitter?

Comment: I'll have you know, I can certainly tell the difference between a goat and a stag!

Answer (score 15):

### He had a "goat fetish" but "wasn't really in love with them".

From a letter that Rowling wrote to a fan in 2008 which recently [was partially posted online](https://twitter.com/noam_gu/status/785610250003030016):

> [image: cropped picture of letter (transcription below)]
>
> **3. Why is one brother in love with goats and the other brother gay?**
> This question made me roar with laughter. Aberforth's goat fetish is [?a ru]nning joke that kept me amused. I don't think he's really in love with [?them, but] it's a good pretext for humor. And I always saw Albus as gay without really knowing why. I knew he had this great friendship with [?Grindelw]ald, and I suspected he overlooked Grindelwald's very obvious faults [??because h]e felt something warmer than ordinary friendship towards him.
> **4. Don't you feel badly for Kendra?**
> [?I thin]k you are asking this independently of question 3, aren't you? I [?hope you'r]e not asking whether I feel sorry for Kendra that she had one [??????] son, and one gay son?

Comment: Hey, that *"one [??????] son, and one gay son"* could contain the answer! What a bummer

Comment: @ShanaTar - I've attempted to reach out to the owner of the letter a few times to request a better scan, but I've never received a response.