# Godfather, Sirius Black - Dogfather as well?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation, sirius-black, animagi

**Is there any evidence that Sirius Black mated with other dogs while he was in his animagus form?** Assuming that such a thing happened, what would the offspring be? A dog or a human?

Comment: I've down-voted, because nothing you've written suggests there was any form of bestiality in the works and given it's a children's book it's rather unlikely,.

Comment: @Edlothiad you said it was a children's book. Now you don't have to restrict yourself to that scope. Just think of the character Sirius Black, his behavior throughout the years, and try to answer

Comment: It is a children's book out-of-universe. It would be an _in-universe_ answer if you wanted one to focus on a character specifically and only their behaviour in the universe. The point remains that there is nothing that suggests this was the case anywhere in the books or in any interviews, supplementary material or anywhere. So your "problem" or "reason for knowing" is unknown and seems in poor taste, at best.

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm asking people to intrapolate Sirius Black's behavior to within the range of his Hogwarts years after his becoming an animagus.

Comment: It *can* be a component of a good story — eg, [Fool Moon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/91477.Fool_Moon) (2001), by Jim Butcher — but there needs to be more to the basis than just delinquent behaviour.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to ask. You seem to be taking it as a given that animagi are capable of mating with ordinary animals, and then asking if it's "possible that he mated with female dogs". According to your premise why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @ibid I also want to know whether the offspring would be a human or a dog  or a hybrid, if mating were possible!!! So, this question just opens the possibility

Comment: @Mr.Riddle - If you want an answer, try figuring out exactly what you want to know and edit the question to reflect that. Right now I honestly can't make heads or tails of it. My two best guesses are "*Can Animagi mate with animals?*" and "*Is there any evidence that Sirius mated with other dogs?*".

Comment: I have downvoted, not because I object to the question's subject matter, but because I do not find the question interesting or useful.

Comment: Reopened following [this meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11728/31394).

Answer (score 8):

### No

There is no evidence that Sirius mated with other dogs while in animagus form. Rowling never wrote anything to suggest he ever did, and we would have no reason to think he would have.

Remember that Sirius only became an Animagus in his fifth year at Hogwarts, and was working with the Order of the Phoenix from immediately after he graduated until when he was locked up in Azkaban. He really didn't have much time to be hanging around as a dog.

Indeed, the only times he seems to have been roaming about as a dog is during the third and fourth book.

It may be worth mentioning that one of the earlier drafts of book four had Sirius staying with other dogs.

> When Padfoot returns in 'Goblet of Fire', I initially had him stay with a highly- eccentric, dog-loving old witch on the edge of Hogsmeade. She kept a pack of ill-assorted dogs, was on constant bad terms with her neighbours because of the barking and the mess, and had welcomed in Sirius, assuming him to be a stray.
>   <sub>[the old jkrowling.com, Edits - "Mopsy the Dog Lover"](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623035037/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=4)</sub>

Of course, due to Rowling's highly consistent opinions about keeping sexuality out of the books, it seems unlikely that any bestiality was implied.

As to what form any potential offspring might take on, we don't really know, since such a thing had never been said to have happened in canon. Rowling seems to describe an animagus as having all the natural properties of the animal save intelligence and life expectancy, so I'd guess the offspring would be dogs (if any offspring could/does exist).

> An  Animagus  is  a  witch  or  wizard  who  can transform  at  will  into  an animal.  While  in their  animal  form,  they retain most  of  their  ability to  think  as  a  human,  their  own sense  of  identity and  their  memories.  They will  also retain normal  human life  expectancy,  even  if  they take  their  animal  form  for  long  periods  of  time.  However, feelings and  emotions are  simplified  and  they  will have many  animal  desires,  feeding  off  whatever  their  animal body craves,  rather  than demanding  human food.
>   <sub>[Pottermore - Animagi](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/short_stories_from_hogwarts_of_heroism_hardship_and_dangerous_hobbies_ebook_english) (behind paywall)</sub>

Comment: What about Aberforth's inappropriate charms on a goat?

Comment: @skooba we don't know what an inappropriate charm on a goat means. in our society it implies something sexual, but why should it be in theirs. 
besides, why would aberforth get charged with performing inappropriate charms on a goat alone if he were doing other things to the goats as well?

I say this, but I wish I could think of an alternative for what an inappropriate charm on a goat would be. lol.

Comment: @Grandpa2390 [Oh, but we do know, we really do...](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39576/what-exactly-did-aberforth-dumbledore-do-to-the-goats)

Comment: @skooba - If you see my answer there, you'll see that Rowling said Aberforth "wasn't really in love with" goats.

Comment: But he did have a "goat fetish."